# Ansible synchronize (rsync) fails

Tags: ssh, ansible, rsync

`ansible.posix.synchronize`, a wrapper for `rsync`, is failing with message

```
"msg": "Warning: Permanently added <host> (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n=========================================================================\nUse of this computer system is for authorized and management approved use\nonly. All usage is subject to monitoring. Unauthorized use is strictly\nprohibited and subject to prosecution and/or corrective action up to and\nincluding termination of employment.\n=========================================================================\nrsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.3]\n"
```

My playbook

```
---
- name: Test rsync
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres

  tasks:
    - name: Populate scripts/common using copy
      copy:
        src: common/
        dest: /home/postgres/scripts/common
     
    - name: Populate scripts/common using rsync
      ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: common/
        dest: /home/postgres/scripts/common
```

`Populate scripts/common using copy` executes with no problem.

Full error output

```
fatal: [<host>]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "sshpass -d3 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u postgres rsync' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /opt/common/ pg_deployment@<host>t:/home/postgres/scripts/common",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync",
            "_substitute_controller": false,
            "archive": true,
            "checksum": false,
            "compress": true,
            "copy_links": false,
            "delay_updates": true,
            "delete": false,
            "dest": "pg_deployment@<host>:/home/postgres/scripts/common",
            "dest_port": null,
            "dirs": false,
            "existing_only": false,
            "group": null,
            "link_dest": null,
            "links": null,
            "mode": "push",
            "owner": null,
            "partial": false,
            "perms": null,
            "private_key": null,
            "recursive": null,
            "rsync_opts": [],
            "rsync_path": "sudo -u postgres rsync",
            "rsync_timeout": 0,
            "set_remote_user": true,
            "src": "/opt/common/",
            "ssh_args": null,
            "ssh_connection_multiplexing": false,
            "times": null,
            "verify_host": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Warning: Permanently added '<host>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n=========================================================================\nUse of this computer system is for authorized and management approved use\nonly. All usage is subject to monitoring. Unauthorized use is strictly\nprohibited and subject to prosecution and/or corrective action up to and\nincluding termination of employment.\n=========================================================================\nrsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.3]\n",
    "rc": 5
}
```

**Notes:**
User `pg_deployment` has passwordless sudo to `postgres`. This ansible playbook is being run inside a docker container.

After messing with it a bit more, I found that I can directly run the rsync command (not using ansible)

```
SSHPASS=<my_ssh_pass> sshpass -e /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u postgres rsync' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' common pg_deployment@<host>:/home/postgres/
```

The only difference I can see is I used `sshpass -e` while ansible defaulted to `sshpass -d#`. Could the credentials ansible was trying to pass in be incorrect? If they are incorrect for `ansible.posix.synchronize` then why aren't they incorrect for other ansible tasks?

**EDIT**
Confirmed that if I run

```
sshpass -d10 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u postgres rsync' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' common pg_deployment@<host>:/home/postgres
```

(I chose random number for the file descriptor `d10`) I get the same error as above

```
"msg": "Warning: Permanently added <host> (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n=========================================================================\nUse of this computer system is for authorized and management approved use\nonly. All usage is subject to monitoring. Unauthorized use is strictly\nprohibited and subject to prosecution and/or corrective action up to and\nincluding termination of employment.\n=========================================================================\nrsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.3]\n"
```

Suggesting that the problem is whatever ansible is using as the file descriptor? It isn't a huge problem since I can just pass in the sshpass as an env variable in my docker container since it's ephemeral, but I still would like to know what is going on with ansible here.

**SOLUTION** (using `command`)

```
---
- name: Create Postgres Cluster
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres

  tasks:
    - name: Create Scripts Directory
      file:
        path: /home/postgres/scripts
        state: directory
     
    - name: Populate scripts/common
      command: sshpass -e /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u postgres rsync' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' common pg_deployment@<host>:/home/postgres/scripts
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      become: no
```